# Slick 3.0.3 warning: method dynamicSession in trait DatabaseFactoryDef is deprecated

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I am using Slick 3.0.3 and I'm happy with the Plain SQL approach mapping result sets to case classes. However, the following code produces the warning `method dynamicSession in trait DatabaseFactoryDef is deprecated: Use the new Action-based API instead`. After researching the Slick documentation and migration jungles I still have to find what they mean with the "new Action-based API". What's the clean, warning-free version of this?

```
import play.api.db.DB
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.backend.Database._
import slick.jdbc.{StaticQuery => Q}
import play.api.Play.current

import models.Tables._

class InstrumentDao {
  def countAllInstruments(): Int = DB.withConnection() { implicit conn =>
    Q.queryNA[Int](s"""select count(*) from "${Instrument.baseTableRow.tableName}"""").first
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new API is imported via the `{driver}.api._` package. Slick 3 is fully asynchronous and it returns `Future` instances for any action that is run using this API, so you need to change the return type of your function accordingly. Just use the `run` function on the `Database` instance and pass it a `DBIOAction` instance created using the method `result` on a statement; an example using the string interpolator to create the actual statement could be:

```
import play.api.db.DB
import scala.concurrent.Future
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._
import play.api.Play.current

import models.Tables._

class InstrumentDao {
  def countAllInstruments(): Future[Int] = db.run(sql"""select count(*) from "${Instrument.baseTableRow.tableName}"""".result.head)
}
```